# VBA for loop does not end the loop

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I'm trying to copy the above cell to below cell with conditions like this
but when i reach 47715, it stops running without any error warning. I have no idea what to do with this.
Hope someone can help me!

```
Dim i As Long

For i = 40 To 180000
    If Cells(i, 33).Value = "A" And IsEmpty(Cells(i + 1, 33)) = True Then
    Cells(i, 33).Copy Cells(i + 1, 33)
    End If
    If Cells(i, 33).Value = "B" And IsEmpty(Cells(i + 1, 33)) = True Then
    Cells(i, 33).Copy Cells(i + 1, 33)
    End If
    If Cells(i, 33).Value = "C" And IsEmpty(Cells(i + 1, 33)) = True Then
    Cells(i, 33).Copy Cells(i + 1, 33)
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

i is too big in for loop

Comment: Why do you think it stops? Insert this before `Next i`.  `if i=50000 then Debug.print "Over"` Is Over printed in the immediate window?

Comment: i is Long so that's not an issue, 47715 < 65k which was the pre-2007 limitation of rows so that's not it either. Are you sure it stops or does it just hang because there's a lot of copying going on?

Comment: Do you have any `On Error` statements in your code? Even if there would be an overflow, a runtime error should pop up. And how can you tell that it stopped at 47715?

Comment: Tested with "A" in AG40. Printed A's to row 180001. Are you sure it stops? It could stop copying if any other value than A, B or C is found in that column until those values are  found again

Comment: As previous experts pointed out, it does not necessarily stop. I would also maybe change the rows like Cells(i, 33).Copy Cells(i + 1, 33) to Cells(i + 1, 33).Value = Cells(i, 33).Value. This will significantly speed things up.

Comment: There is no need to check for `IsEmpty(...) = TRUE`, you can just check `IsEmpty(...)`, so the first line with a condition becomes `If Cells(i, 33).Value = "A" And IsEmpty(Cells(i + 1, 33)) Then`. Good luck.

Comment: By the way, why do you always repeat the check on the `IsEmpty()`? You might write something like `IF IsEmpty(...) THEN IF cells(...) = "A" THEN ... END IF, IF cells(...) = "B" THEN ... END IF ... END IF` (I mean a nested IF-loop), that might make everything clearer.

Comment: ... and as you are always doing the same thing, you can replace `if A and D then action, if B and D then action, if C and D then Action` by `if (A OR B OR C) AND D then action`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternate solution using a dictionary for determining matching values that should be copied. Heavily commented to assist with understanding.

```
Sub tgr()
    
    'Define code variables
    Const sColumn As String = "AG"      'This is the column that will be looped over (AG is column 33)
    Const lStartRow As Long = 40        'This is the row that the looping will start on
    Const lFinalRow As Long = 180000    'This is the row that the looping will end on
    Const bMatchCase As Boolean = False 'True for case sensitive matches
    
    'Define value matching requirements that will result in a copy using a dictionary
    Dim hCopyValues As Object:  Set hCopyValues = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    If bMatchCase = False Then hCopyValues.CompareMode = vbTextCompare  'Make dictionary case matching dependent on defined code variable
    
    'Add keys to the dictionary, adjust the Array() portion to add/remove/edit the keys for the matching values that will be copied
    Dim vKey As Variant
    For Each vKey In Array("A", "B", "C")
        hCopyValues.Add vKey, 1
    Next vKey
    
    'Define worksheet and data range
    Dim ws As Worksheet:    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    Dim rData As Range:     Set rData = ws.Range(ws.Cells(lStartRow, sColumn), ws.Cells(lFinalRow, sColumn))
    
    'Convert data range to an array
    Dim aData() As Variant: aData = rData.Value
    
    'Loop over the array
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(aData, 1) To UBound(aData, 1) - 1
        'Check if current value matches a defined value in the dictionary, and also if the next value is empty
        If hCopyValues.Exists(aData(i, 1)) And Len(aData(i + 1, 1)) = 0 Then
            'Matching value found and next value confirmed empty, copy current value to next row
            aData(i + 1, 1) = aData(i, 1)
        End If
    Next i
    
    'Return updated array data to the worksheet
    rData.Value = aData
    
End Sub
```

Comment: OH HOLY GOSHHH, THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!! it works now, all row has been filled as I want now. is this even real, what did you do!?

Comment: ohhhhh i don't know how it happened, but it works super well! i can't even understand your code but you have my BIG THANK YOU here!

Comment: You've marked this as the answer but the code from VBasic2008 is a lot faster:
tigeravatar
0,7773438 seconds,
VBasic2008
0,4296875 seconds. Why did you choose this code, did I miss something?

Answer (score 2):

### Fill Gaps in Column

[image]

- Note that this assumes that there are no formulas and that you want to copy only values (no formats). On your roughly 200k rows, It should run in a blink of an eye (maybe a slower one).

```vb
Sub FillGapsInColumn()

    Const FirstRow As Long = 40
    Const LastRow As Long = 59
    Const Col As Variant = "AG" ' or 33
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    Dim rg As Range:
    Set rg = ws.Range(ws.Cells(FirstRow, Col), ws.Cells(LastRow, Col))
    
    Dim Data() As Variant: Data = rg.Value
    
    Dim r As Long, rStr As String, IsMatchFound As Boolean
    
    For r = 1 To LastRow - FirstRow
        If Not IsMatchFound Then rStr = CStr(Data(r, 1))
        If IsEmpty(Data(r + 1, 1)) Then ' is empty
        'If Len(CStr(Data(r + 1, 1))) = 0 Then ' is blank
            If Not IsMatchFound Then
                Select Case UCase(rStr)
                    Case "A", "B", "C"
                        IsMatchFound = True
                End Select
            End If
            If IsMatchFound Then Data(r + 1, 1) = rStr
        Else
            IsMatchFound = False
        End If
    Next r
                        
    rg.Value = Data

    MsgBox "Gaps in column filled.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It is probably just slow. I tried to speed it up with:

```
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
```

This runs in 8 seconds, but I ran it on an empty sheet

```
Sub x()
    Dim i As Long
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        For i = 40 To 180000
            If .Cells(i, 33).Value = "A" And IsEmpty(.Cells(i + 1, 33)) = True Then
               .Cells(i, 33).Copy .Cells(i + 1, 33)
            End If
            If .Cells(i, 33).Value = "B" And IsEmpty(.Cells(i + 1, 33)) = True Then
               .Cells(i, 33).Copy .Cells(i + 1, 33)
            End If
            If .Cells(i, 33).Value = "C" And IsEmpty(.Cells(i + 1, 33)) = True Then
               .Cells(i, 33).Copy .Cells(i + 1, 33)
            End If
           ' Debug.Print i;
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Also, you might want to set:

```
Application.Calculation=xlCalculationManual
For i = 40 To 180000
```

before the for loop
and:

```
Next i
Application.Calculation=xlCalculationAutomatic
```

after the loop

This runs in 15 seconds, with data in column 33:

```
Sub x()
    Dim i As Long, t As Single
    t = Timer
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        For i = 40 To 180000
            If .Cells(i, 33).Value = "A" And IsEmpty(.Cells(i + 1, 33)) Then
               ' improvement from @Mika O.
               .Cells(i + 1, 33).Value = .Cells(i, 33).Value 
            End If
            If .Cells(i, 33).Value = "B" And IsEmpty(.Cells(i + 1, 33)) Then
               .Cells(i + 1, 33).Value = .Cells(i, 33).Value
            End If
            If .Cells(i, 33).Value = "C" And IsEmpty(.Cells(i + 1, 33)) Then
               .Cells(i + 1, 33).Value = .Cells(i, 33).Value
            End If
        Next i
    End With
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Debug.Print Timer - t & " seconds"
End Sub
```

Comment: So you didn't have any values in AG40:AG180000 + empty cells?

Comment: No I didn't, data in those cells would make it slower. Just running the code for the loop and checking cells takes 8 seconds. This definitely needs to run without calculation and probably without screenupdating

Comment: Hi! Thank a lot for the recommendation, I tried it. it was better than mine, somehow it stops when reaching AG56000. but it's helpful! :D